# How can I export Notes created in Outlook to Memo in Samsung Galaxy A3

Tags: outlook

I'm new to Samsung Galaxy smartphones and just got a Galaxy A3. I already sync Contacts, Calendars and To Do from Outlook to my smartphone using Smart Switch app, however I haven't been able to find a way to export or sync my Outlook Notes to my Samsung Galaxy A3 smartphone.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone and certain models of BlackBerry smartphone can sync directly with Microsoft Outlook using iTunes or BlackBerry Desktop Software, respectively, but Outlook doesn't directly support Android with this option as far as I know.

So this is where third party apps like [VCOrginizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vecal.vcorganizerlite) comes into play. It allows you to Sync Outlook notes from WiFi. If I were you, I'd certainly check it out.